# ElasticSearch - RestHighLevelClient - listener timeout after waiting for [30000] ms

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

While indexing `100k` doucments am getting `listener` timeout exception for the below line

```
IndexResponse response = SearchEngineClient.getInstance2().index(request);
```

Please find the complete stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: listener timeout after waiting f
or [30000] ms
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClie
nt.java:663)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:22
2)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:19
4)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighL
evelClient.java:443)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEn
tity(RestHighLevelClient.java:429)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClien
t.java:312)
        at com.es.utility.DocumentIndex.main(DocumentIndex.java:255)
```

Comment: Maybe use bulk api ? see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html

Comment: Maybe send smaller bulk queries with less documents.

Comment: @Val - i solved this problem by adding `setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(90000000)` while creating instance for `RestHighLevelClient`. But now am facing `java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` issue. i have created a separate question for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348939/elasticsearch-resthighlevelclient-java-io-ioexception-an-existing-connection

Comment: Increasing the timeout is probably not the solution, you need to send smaller bulks.

Comment: @Val - do you have any examples for smaller bulk?

Comment: simply send less data in your bulk request

Comment: @Val - I have raised a separate question for the same in detail.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it works with me

```
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost(HOST, PORT))
                .setRequestConfigCallback(
                    new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public RequestConfig.Builder customizeRequestConfig(
                                RequestConfig.Builder requestConfigBuilder) {
                            return requestConfigBuilder
                                .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                                .setSocketTimeout(60000);
                        }
                    }).setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(60000);
```