# ElasticSearch - RestHighLevelClient java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, http, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am fetch `100K` plus documents from an Index using single query. For that am using `ScrollSearch` API. After that am iterating each and every doucments one by one and adding one more field into that and creating a new index for that.

Am using `RestHighLevelClient` for the connectivity between Java Code and ElasticSearch. I have set `Timeout` options for `25` hours (setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(90000000)).

But, still am getting the below exception after 30 minutes

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionInputBufferImpl.fill(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:204)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.fillBuffer(AbstractMessageParser.java:136)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:241)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My ElasticSearch server is running on remote machine. Once i got this exception, my remote machine ES server also get shutdown automatically.

Please find the code below, where i creating instance for `RestHighLevelClient`.

```
private static RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("My_Server.com", 9200, "http"), 
            new HttpHost("My_Server.com", 9201, "http"))
            .setRequestConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
                @Override
                public RequestConfig.Builder customizeRequestConfig(RequestConfig.Builder requestConfigBuilder) {
                    return requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(90000000)//25hours
                            .setSocketTimeout(90000000);

                }
            })
            .setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(90000000);


    private static RestHighLevelClient instance4 = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);

    public static RestHighLevelClient getInstance3() {
        return instance4;
    }
```

Comment: This usually indicates not enough heap allocated. Anyway why are you writing to a new index that would double the needed memory if it's on the same cluster. If you just want to update the documents why not use update_by_query API which is more optimal?

Comment: @sramalingam24 - Am getting `filePath` from existing index., By using the `filePath` and reading the actual file (which is in local drive ). I Encode the file to base64 and creating a new index with all the exisiting index fields + Encoded File contents. So, for this activity how can i make use of `update_by_query` api ?

Comment: So the new field is just the encoded file content? Why would you need to do that? This means you are storing the contents of the file twice

Comment: nope., in my first index i have only file path., in my second index (that am creating via java code) am copying all the fields from first index and also adding the encoded fileContents too.

Comment: Can you post the entire code?

Comment: @sramalingam24 - I have raised a separate question for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442457/elasticsearch-taking-8hours-to-index-23gb-of-pdf-20k-documents-using-java-ap