# ElasticSearch - taking more time (8 hours) to index 23 gb of pdf (20k documents) using java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am indexing pdf using java api. I have installed `ingest-attachement processor plugin` and from my java code, am converting PDF into base64 and indexing encoded format of PDF.

Actually, PDFs are available in my machine d:\ drive. The file path are available in ElasticSearch index named as `documents_local`. So, am fetching all the records from `documents_local` index and getting the file path. Then, am reading the pdf file and encode into base64. Then indexing them.

For this process, am using scrollRequest API to fetch file path from index, because am having more that `100k` documents. so, for indexing `20000` PDFs its taking 8 hours of time with the below java code.

How can i increase the throughput or speed up this process. Its taking very long time to indexing `100k` documents.

```
public class DocumentIndex {

    private final static String INDEX = "documents_local";  
    private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment"; 
    private final static String TYPE = "doc";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 3 * 1024;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient2 = null;
        Document doc=new Document();

        logger.info("Started Indexing the Document.....");

        //Fetching Id, FilePath & FileName from Document Index. 
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
        searchRequest.types(TYPE);
        final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(60L)); //part of Scroll API

        searchRequest.scroll(scroll); //part of Scroll API
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();

        searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().search(searchRequest);
        String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId(); //part of Scroll API
        SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

        //part of Scroll API -- Starts
        while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) { 
            SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId); 
            scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
            searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().searchScroll(scrollRequest);
            scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
            searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

            File all_files_path = new File("d:\\All_Files_Path.txt");
            File available_files = new File("d:\\Available_Files.txt");
            File missing_files = new File("d:\\Missing_Files.txt");

            int totalFilePath=1;
            int totalAvailableFile=1;
            int missingFilecount=1;

            Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;
            for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {

                StringBuilder result = null;
                String encodedfile = null;
                File file=null;
                Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();

                if(sourceAsMap != null) {  
                    doc.setId((int) sourceAsMap.get("id"));
                    doc.setApp_language(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("app_language")));
                }

                String filepath=doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename());
                file = new File(filepath);

                if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {

                    //base64 conversion Starts
                    FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader2 = new FileInputStream(file);
                    try ( BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStreamReader2, BUFFER_SIZE); ) {
                         try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(available_files, true))  ){
                            out.println("Available File Count --->"+totalAvailableFile+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
                            totalAvailableFile++;
                        }
                        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
                        result = new StringBuilder();
                        byte[] chunk = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        int len = 0;
                        while ( (len = in.read(chunk)) == BUFFER_SIZE ) {
                             result.append( encoder.encodeToString(chunk) );
                        }
                        if ( len > 0 ) {
                             chunk = Arrays.copyOf(chunk,len);
                             result.append( encoder.encodeToString(chunk) );
                        }
                    }
                    //base64 conversion Ends

                }

                jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
                jsonMap.put("id", doc.getId());
                jsonMap.put("app_language", doc.getApp_language());
                jsonMap.put("fileContent", result);

                String id=Long.toString(doc.getId());

                IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ATTACHMENT, "doc", id )
                        .source(jsonMap)
                        .setPipeline(ATTACHMENT);

                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new File("d:\\exception.txt"));
                try {

                    IndexResponse response = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().index(request); 

                } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
                    if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace(printStream);
                }

                totalFilePath++;

            }

        }

        ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest(); 
        clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
        ClearScrollResponse clearScrollResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().clearScroll(clearScrollRequest);
        boolean succeeded = clearScrollResponse.isSucceeded();
        ////part of Scroll API -- Ends

        logger.info("Indexing done.....");

    }

}
```

Comment: Just a few suggestions here, separate the search and the indexing into two steps, use nulk indexing in multiple threads, check out cbor format instead of base64 encoding. I have a similar app to yours but use .Net client and I use all the above.

Comment: *bulk indexing not nulk

Comment: @sramalingam24 - do have any samples on how to creating thread for this requirement

Comment: I'd be curious about the same test with https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler

Comment: @dadoonet - Am using `ingest-attachment Processor plugin` in my project. `FSCrawler` is different from `ingest` ..? If i use this project., do i need to do modify any other settings..?

Comment: FSCrawler can crawl your drive and extract locally all the text before sending the extracted text to elasticsearch. Which means that less data will go through the bulk API.

Comment: I have raised a separate question for the same., Where i have created Consumer & Producer class to separate the indexing process.